# Alerts interval times jquery mysql php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

sorry but someone have a example of alerts in realtime for example

if a agent pass 10 minutes in lunch give a alert and that depend of time is insert in the database and insert in the table lates

will be very useful thank you

what I really want to do if compare it for make the different alerts but I dont know how to do it .. this dont work

alert.php:

```
<?php
$host = "" ;
$user = "" ;
$pw = "" ;
$db = "operator" ;

$fechaactual = Date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw) or die ("problemas al conectar");
$database=mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die ("problemas al conectar la bd");

$re = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM operator ");
while($m=mysql_fetch_array($re)){
$ahi = (strtotime($m['tiempo']));
$ahi1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+10 minutes", $ahi));
$ingresada = strtotime($ahi1);
$now = strtotime($fechaactual);
$lsk = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lates WHERE id_op ='".$m['ID']."'");   
if($ingresada > $now){
if(mysql_num_rows($lsk) == 0) {
echo "<script>";
echo "alert('".$m['nombre']."  over pass the  ".$m['status']."');";
echo "</script>";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO lates (id_op,nombre) VALUES     ('".$m['ID']."','".$m['nombre']."')");
}else {
echo "is already inserted";}
}
}
?>
```

here is the script :

```
<div id="alertas">
<?php include("alertas.php"); ?>
</div>
<script>
function conn() {
    $("#alertas").load("alertas.php");
}
setInterval("conn()", 100);
</script>
```

my table operator ...

```
CREATE TABLE `operator` (
`nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('available','break1','break2','lunch','out') character set swe7 NOT NULL   default 'available',
`tiempo` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`msj` varchar(30) default NULL,
`ID` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

and my table lates:

```
   CREATE TABLE `lates` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id_op` int(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: We are happy to help you solve specific problems with your own code, but we will not (in most cases) write your code or development plan for you. Please update your question to explain what you expect to happen, what you have tried, and how your attempt failed.

Comment: ok sorry you are right :D

Comment: I did the change thank you for the advice George Cummins

Comment: someone can change the status on Hold ?? I make the changes thank you

Comment: Thank you for providing your code. However, your question still does not explain how the code fails to meet your needs. Will you provide specific information about what this code is supposed to do and what it is actually doing now? Be sure to include any error messages you receive and a detailed description of the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP of `alert.php`:

```
if ($something_your_alert == true) {
    $return['status'] = true;
} else {
    $return['status'] = false;
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Add on `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag of Ajax processing:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/alert.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: parameters,
  success: function(data){
     // action of success, append to div
     if (data.status)
     {
         $("#divres").append("okay");
     }
     else
     {
         $("#divres").append("failed");
     }
     }
  },
  error: function(){
     $("#divres").append("failed");
  }
});
```

And put in `<body>` tag of div:

```
<div id="divres"></div>
```

Comment: thanks marin sagovac sorry im new with this jquery thing :D .. I have a question how I make the conection with my database in mysql and compre with the field "time for example" and thanks :)